# Non linear classifier against a linearly separable training set

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I was thinking about the risks hided under training a non linear classifier against a labelled (large enough) dataset which is linearly separable.

What would be the main classification misleadings we can come up with? Some example?

Answer (score 2):

In the [bias-variance tradeoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff), a non-linear classifier has, in general, a larger variance than the linear one. If the dataset is generated by a linearly-separable process but the measurements are noisy, then it will be more susceptible to overfitting.

However, if the dataset is large enough and the classifier is unbiased, then a non-linear classifier would eventually produce effectively a separating hyperplane.

Comment: You can check for overfitting with learning curves. Plot the learning curves with the training and cross validation errors. If the cross validation error gets bigger with increasing complexity of your model or increasing size of the dataset your model is probably overfitting your data.